# Mysql AES_Decrypt from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, aes

I am trying to use AES_DECRYPT to decrypt multiple columns from a table, how can I do that?

What I am trying:

```
SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c AES_DECRYPT(column_a, column_b, column_c 'p4ss0wrd1') 
FROM dates_table1;
```

Could someone guide me thru the right syntax? Or if its possible to decrypt everything directly from a table.

Comment: what error/problem are you experiencing? You have a missing comma, and also AES_DECRYPT only accepts a string as argument, not a series of different ones. And why do you want to do this? Did you split the encrypted data between the three columns originally? Why? Anyway you'd probably have to _concat_ them back together in order to pass to the function - as I just mentioned you can't specify a list of columns like that, only a single string.

Comment: 064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax . Yes, only 3 columns is encrypted using AES, but different kind of data.

Comment: "different kind of data"...what do you mean? They contain separate encrypted strings? In that case you can't decrypt them all at once, each must be decrypted separately (i.e. a separate call to the aes_decrypt function for each column).

Comment: Its the same string/decryption password. By different data I mean eg: column_a = full name, column_b = e-mail address, column_c = ID number. What I am trying to do is to export a list of those.

Comment: so? It's not the same _data_. If they were encrypted separately then each must be decrypted _separately_. The decrypt function only accepts one string at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AES_DECRYPT function only accepts one value at a time (I mean one encrypted string, plus the password). Also, if the values were encrypted separately then it makes no sense to try and decrypt them all as one thing.

Just call the function separately for each column:

```
SELECT 
  column_a, 
  column_b, 
  column_c, 
  AES_DECRYPT(column_a, 'p4ss0wrd1'),
  AES_DECRYPT(column_b, 'p4ss0wrd1'),
  AES_DECRYPT(column_c, 'p4ss0wrd1')
FROM 
  dates_table1;
```

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I am a newbie at mysql.
Just one last question, how can I export this data to a excel or text file? Maybe using php?

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark the answer as "accepted" when you can. Thanks. P.S. You should probably consider using a stronger encryption password. See examples in the documentation link above.

Comment: "how can I export this to text file"...just ask the internet: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+export+to+text+file&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=mysql+export+to+text+fil&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3664j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 - if you export to CSV then Excel can open it quite easily.

Comment: Thanks again, however the table that I am decrypting have like 364 pages, I've observed that the decryption is only happening on the last page. Do you know how to decrypt every page since beginning?

Comment: pages? Are you talking about https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-page-structure.html ? I'm not quite sure what you're referring to.

Comment: I think I mean rows. I want to get all the data on that table, not only the recent ones. Btw I am using Navicat to run the query, maybe it is a program limitation?

Comment: @AlvaroVeiga Do you mean that only one row is returned at all, or that 364 rows come back but only the last one has decrypted values in it? Or something else? I don't know what navicat is or does, sorry, so I can't commit on that. If you run the query using a standard tool e.g. MySQL Workbench, does it work as expected or not?